# Issue with adding instance of class object to ArrayList, what am I doing wrong? [JAVA]

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, constructor

I am trying to add an object of class `Track` to my `ArrayList` of `Track`, playlist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlayList {
    private String playList;
    private ArrayList <Track> myTracks;

    //constructors
    public PlayList(String name) {
        this.playList = name;
    }

    public PlayList(String name, ArrayList<Track> tracks) {
        this.playList = name;
        this.myTracks = tracks;
    }

    public addTrack(Track track){
        myTracks.add(0,track)
    }
}
```

But both my constructor and `addTrack` method fails, showing java.lang.NullPointerException

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you hven't initialize your arraylist hence your method fails, try only constructing an object your constructors must work

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `addTrack()` should have a return type

Answer (score 2):

You never get an exception in your constructor. There is no chance at all.

And the reason for add method is you are using `myTracks.add(0,track)` and you never initialize your list

```
private List<Track> myTracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `ArrayList` and code to the *interface*.
Use : `private List<Track> myTracks = new ArrayList<>();` (for java versions below java -7, use `new ArrayList<Track>();`)

Comment: But why exception is constructor ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - I guess the OP's code is incomplete. He must be trying to add items to `myTracks` . His current code doesn't compile

Comment: Yah. Probably he failed to understand the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I think your constructor fails because you try to initialize object from  `playList` like this :-

```
playList myList = new playList();
```

This will give you error because there is no defualt constructor and it is not created by default (The default constructor is automatically generated unless you define another constructor)

If you didn't create your playList object like this there is **no way** you got an exception in the constructor

And the reason for addmethod error is you initialized your list

You have to do this :-

```
private List<Track> myTracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "NullPointerException" in the Arraylist because you have not initialized it first. You can add items in list only after initializing it first.
So write like this instead and try -

```
private List<Track> myTracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
```

As far as the constructor is concerned i think there you didnt give the required parameters. When you are calling the constructor of PlayList class you need to pass the correct values as parameters which you defined(2 Constructors in this case). if you don't then it will throw an error because there is no default(no argument) constructor. So try like this -

```
PlayList myList=new PlayList("//give name","//ArrayList name which contains the tracks")
```